# FFmpeg iOS RTSP stream save to disk - Need Example on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, stream, rtsp, disk

I am looking for an **example** on how to use **FFmpeg** once integrated to an **iOS**  project in **Swift** to **save an RTSP stream to disk**.

In terminal macOS I can do:

> ffmpeg -i rtsp://cool:url@media/media.amp -b 900k -vcodec copy -r 60 -y MySuperCoolFFmpegVideo.mp4

This gives me exactly what I need.

Comment: ever found a solution?

Comment: Not yet, I ended up using a node server that implements HLS which encapsulates RTSP and worked pretty good. It is NOT ideal though.

Comment: @moyoteg: did you save hls (m3u8) video to gallery ? If, any reference please

Comment: any solution to this problem?